# Raspberry pi crontab won't restart service

Tags: cron

I have a raspberry pi that is running an outdoor camera.  Occasionally, the camera 'locks' and I have to restart the service as root and it starts working again.  Since the camera is outside it's in a sealed case and I'm try all other options before I decide I need to remove and rebuild.

So I tried to set up a cron job to restart the service every 2 hours.

First I tried restarting the service directly in cron

In crontab I had:

```
0 */2 * * *  service motion restart
```

But it never restarted.

So to make sure cron was working, I changed my crontab to:

```
0 */2 * * * service motion restart
0 */2 * * * logger motion should have restarted
```

I checked the `/var/log/messages` sometime later and sure enough, multiple messages saying 'motion should have restarted' but no logs showing that it ACTUALLY restarted. And indeed it had not when I checked the motion.log file and it was still locked up.

So I created a script called  /home/pi/restart_camera

```
#!/bin/bash
service motion restart
logger script ran to restart camera
```

and then changed `cron` to say

```
0 */2 * * * /home/pi/restart_camera
0 */2 * * * logger motion should have restarted
```

But when I checked sometime later, the camera was in a locked state, but /var/log/messages had multiple messages saying 'script ran to restart camera' and 'motion should have restarted' but still no logs showing that it ACTUALLY restarted. And again it had not when I checked the motion.log file and it was still locked up.

When I run the script as root from the command line, it indeed restarts the motion service.

I added a redirect and the error it gave is the following:

/home/pi/restart_camera: line 2: service: command not found

Any ideas here?

Comment: Your question seems to be formatted improperly. Please use `code fences` when necessary. I've added some to show you how - please review & modify your question as required.

Comment: "`I added a redirect ...`" What redirect? Where is it - how did you do this? And please make it clear: Do you need `sudo` to run the job successfully from the command line, or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is currently unclear on some points & I've requested clarification in the comments. Until then, this may help:

`cron` doesn't have the same PATH that you have in the interactive shell (`bash`), and the system cannot find the executable file(s) you've specified in your `crontab`. There are a couple of ways to solve this, but perhaps the *cleanest* is to simply specify the full path in your `crontab`:

```
0 */2 * * * /usr/sbin/service motion restart
```

I have no idea what `motion` is, or where it is located. You may need to add its full path also.

You stated, "*When I run the script as root from the command line, it indeed restarts the motion service.*".

If root privileges are required to run this program, then you will need to run it under the `root crontab` instead of ***your*** `crontab`:

```
$ sudo crontab -e
```

Once the `root crontab` opens in the editor, make your `crontab` entries ***without using sudo***; i.e.:

```
0 */2 * * * /usr/sbin/service motion restart
```

Some other items:

1. The script you created will have the same issues as your initial `crontab` entries: You should specify the script's full path in `crontab` ***AND*** you must specify the full path of your executables *in the script*.
2. `logger` may not be capturing the most important information: `stderr`. Use a `redirect` instead to capture `stderr` and `stdout` to a file:

   ```
   0 */2 * * * /usr/sbin/service motion restart >> /home/pi/mycronlog.txt 2>&1
   ```
3. As a "learning experiment", try adding the following to your `crontab`:

   ```
   0 */2 * * * /usr/bin/logger <<< echo "This is your PATH in cron: $PATH"
   ```

Comment: You are exactly correct. I needed the path. Thanks.